# Django sends email to some weird "m, m" address

Tags: django, django-settings

I tried to setup ADMINS variable in settings.py to get email on 500 error.
I've read through the settings documentation, and defined the following:

```
ADMINS = (('{name}', '{email@mycompany.com}'))  
SERVER_EMAIL = '{account name}@localhost'  
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.{mycompany}.com']
```

For some reason I receive an email with *"Undeliverable: [Django] ERROR (EXTERNAL IP): Internal Server Error:"*
I've noticed that in original message headers, the email is being sent to *"m, m"*, which I did not define.

Any idea what that could be?

Thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is that Django is expecting a tuple of tuples in ADMINS, but you have actually only given a single tuple: the outer parentheses are effectively ignored, because in Python it is not the parens that define a tuple, but the comma.

The code in the mail_admins function tries to extract the emails from the setting by doing `[a[1] for a in settings.ADMINS]`, so in your case it will take the second letter of the name and the second letter of the email address - presumably those both happen to be "m".

Do this instead:

```
ADMINS = (('{name}', '{email@mycompany.com}'),)
```

Note the extra comma before the final close paren.